# How do I configure the GNOME gdm login screen?

Tags: gnome, arch-linux, login, gdm

I recently installed Arch Linux and have it mostly set up. With many other Linux distributions, there is a tool that is used to configure the look and feel of the login screen. I would like to change the wallpaper used, the date/time format from something like "Sat 6:27 PM" to "26 Feb 11 18:27", and the refresh rate of the monitor (it's fine when I'm logged in, but not at the login screen).

Where can I find these configuration options or (preferably) a GNOME application to allow for me to make these configuration changes?

Answer (score 13):

The [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Main_Page) is a very good source of information. [This](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME) is where I found the following:

> To configure the GDM theme use this
>   command:
>
> ```
> sudo -u gdm dbus-launch gnome-appearance-properties
> ```
>
> For more configuration options, use
>   this command:
>
> ```
> sudo -u gdm dbus-launch gconf-editor
> ```
>
> And modify the following hierarchies:
>
> ```
> /apps/gdm/simple-greeter
> /desktop/gnome/interface
> /desktop/gnome/background
> ```

You may end up with an Xauth error. If that happens, try `gksudo` instead of `sudo`. If the error persists, you can do this:

```
xauth list $DISPLAY
```

This gives you the xauth cookie being used by your user. Copy the output, then run the following, replacing "" with the output of the previous command.

```
sudo su -u gdm
xauth add <cookie>
dbus-launch gnome-appearance-properties
```

This logs you in as the gdm user, adds the cookie, permitting gdm to use your display, and launches gnome-appearance-properties.

Comment: When I try to run "sudo -u gdm dbus-launch gconf-editor", I get "No protocol specified" and "Couldn't exec gconf-editor: No such file or directory". I'll re-read that page and poke around, though.

Comment: @thomas-owens I added some steps to try.

Comment: So I did this and launched gnome-appearance-properties, which is just the Appearance Preferences from System > Preferences > Appearance. There's no way to adjust anything about the login screen on that application. I'm now looking at gconf-editor, which I had to install separately. Nothing jumps out at me, but there are a ton of options, so I'll have to read some docs and poke around a little.

Comment: I should have added that the login screen is the background image for the gdm user. Previous versions of GDM supported themes, but it no longer does.

Comment: I get `sudo: unkown user: gdm` from doing what @ShawnJ.Goff suggests

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found to do it was to modify/replace the file:

```
/usr/share/backgrounds/linuxmint/default_background.jpg
```

The file is 1920x1200 and I've only tried replacing it with another jpg of the same resolution.

You may want to make a backup of the original `default_background.jpg` just in case.

After replacing it you can test how the image will look by locking your computer.

Comment: much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The only one that worked for me on Arch Linux:

```
sudo -u gdm dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver picture-uri 'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/gnome/picture.jpg'
```

Then, you can verify it worked:

```
sudo -u gdm gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver picture-uri
```

Or verify using dconf:

```
sudo -u gdm dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/picture-uri
```

Answer (score 0):

At least on my systems the default login provides a menu option to change the configuration from the login screen.

But the monitor refresh is not controlled by GDM, that is an X server configuration, edited in the xorg.conf file.