# Can the background of the log-in screen of linux mint 11 change?

Tags: login, linux-mint, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I configure the GNOME gdm login screen?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8268/how-do-i-configure-the-gnome-gdm-login-screen)

How can I change the background picture of the log in screen of linux mint katya?