# How to hide mouse cursor in gnome-shell and gdm display manager?

Tags: debian, mouse, gnome-shell, gdm3

I'm trying hide the mouse cursor my Debian Jessie with gnome-shell and gdm display manager.

I could easily do if I know how can pass the argument `-nocursor` to X server with the GDM Display manager.

If I do not use GDM is simple:

```
startx -- -nocursor
```

How do I can do it?

Comment: The command / arguments to start Xorg is [hardcoded in gdm](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77342) so I don't think there's a trivial way to accomplish that unless you are willing to patch gdm and add `-nocursor` to the `#define X_SERVER_ARG_FORMAT` line.

Comment: Depending on your setup, you may be able to use something like unclutter. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/660613/1858225), which has several useful answers, including `unclutter` and alternatives.